# pandas find intersection point of two lines in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Tow lines with its points:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'y':[262,306,360,360,380,380],'x':[0,30,75,174,199,837]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'y':[410,400,170,170,100],'x':[0,8.8,39.8,80.6,83.7]})
```

[image]

How to find the intersection point of these two lines and put the point in dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get all lines' equations `y = mx + beta` between consecutive data points in each dataframe
2. For each of the above lines `(m, beta)`, also keep the boundaries `(x,y)`
3. Find intersection points `x = (beta2 - beta1) / (m1 - m2)` between lines of the two dataframes
4. Accept only the intersection points that are between the described boundaries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# our dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"y": [262, 306, 360, 360, 380, 380], "x": [0, 30, 75, 174, 199, 837]}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"y": [410, 400, 170, 170, 100], "x": [0, 8.8, 39.8, 80.6, 83.7]})


def find_intersection(first_line, second_line):
    """
    this functions takes the variables m and beta of two lines
    and returns the intersection point coordinates x, y
    """
    x = (second_line[1] - first_line[1]) / (first_line[0] - second_line[0])
    y = first_line[0] * x + first_line[1]
    return x, y


def find_m_beta(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
    this functions calculates m and beta of a line
    given two coordinates x1,y1 and x2,y2
    """
    if x2 != x1:
        m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    else:
        m = 0
    beta = y2 - m * x2

    return m, beta


def find_m_beta_bounds(df):
    """
    this function finds the equations of all lines 
    that can be created by the given dataframe.
    It only calculates lines of points that are consequent.
    For example:
        index     x  y
          0       0  1
          1       1  2
          2       3  4
    Given the above dataframe, the function will find two equations:
    namely m and beta of the line between points with indexes 0 and 1
    and  m and beta of the line between points with indexes 1 and 2.
    It will also return the boundaries of these lines
    """
    data_points = df.to_numpy()
    vars = []
    bounds_x, bounds_y = [], []

    # find m, beta and bounds for each line in df
    for idx, item in enumerate(data_points):
        if idx == len(data_points) - 1:
            break
        x1 = item[1]
        y1 = item[0]
        x2 = data_points[idx + 1][1]
        y2 = data_points[idx + 1][0]

        m, beta = find_m_beta(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        vars.append([m, beta])
        bounds_x.append([min([x1, x2]), max([x1, x2])])
        bounds_y.append([min([y1, y2]), max([y1, y2])])
    return vars, bounds_x, bounds_y


# get vars (m,beta) and bounds (x,y) for each line in df1 and in df2
# where y = mx +beta
vars_df1, bounds_x_df1, bounds_y_df1 = find_m_beta_bounds(df1)
vars_df2, bounds_x_df2, bounds_y_df2 = find_m_beta_bounds(df2)


# find interesections of all lines of df1 and df2
all_intersections_x, all_intersections_y = [], []
for idx, item in enumerate(vars_df1):
    for idx_, item_ in enumerate(vars_df2):
        x, y = find_intersection(item, item_)
        # accept intersection only if (x,y) are in bounds of both investigated lines
        if (
            x >= bounds_x_df1[idx][0]
            and x <= bounds_x_df1[idx][1]
            and y >= bounds_y_df1[idx][0]
            and y <= bounds_y_df1[idx][1]
            and x >= bounds_x_df2[idx_][0]
            and x <= bounds_x_df2[idx_][1]
            and y >= bounds_y_df2[idx_][0]
            and y <= bounds_y_df2[idx_][1]
        ):
            all_intersections_x.append(x)
            all_intersections_y.append(y)


# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(df1["x"], df1["y"], color="red")
ax.plot(df2["x"], df2["y"], color="green")
ax.scatter(all_intersections_x, all_intersections_y)
plt.show()
```

Result
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the hard work. It is not an easy task.

Comment: @Brom did that work for you?

Comment: Just used this - really impressive code (to me at least) Thanks!